# How to fix the error Too Many Redirects error in HTTP subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

I transfered a site from a primary domain to a subdomain. But i got the error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` .

I tried to clean .htaccess with no result

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

AddType text/x-component .htc

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://kosmimashop.digital-media.gr/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^home/ index.php?page=home&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^offers/ index.php?page=offers&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^cart/ index.php?page=cart&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^orders/ index.php?page=orders&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^addresses/ index.php?page=addresses&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in your first redirect rule?

Comment: If that rule is implemented in the http host `kosmimashop.digital-media.gr` then certainly it will result in a redirection loop, since you rewrite from http to http... I guess instead you want to rewrite from http to https...